# Is the convex function of a DC function convex ? Or is it DC?

Tags: convex-analysis

Suppose function $g(x)$ is convex in $x$ and $h(x)$ is DC in $x$ (i.e., is the Difference of two Convex functions), is the composite fuction $H(x):=g(h(x))$ convex in $x$?
Here, DC is short for difference of convex functions, that is, $h(x)$ can be expressed as,
\begin{equation}
h(x) = h_1(x) - h_2(x),
\end{equation}
where, $h_1(x)$ and $h_2(x)$ are convex in $x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, the composition $H$ is *not* convex. As a counterexample, let $D=[2,3]\subset\mathbb{R}$. Let $h_1,h_2:D\to\mathbb{R}$ be given by

$$ h_1(x)=\frac{1}{x}\quad\text{and}\quad h_2(x)=x^2. $$

Then $h\equiv h_1-h_2$ is d.c. Let $g:D\to\mathbb{R}$ be given by

$$ g(x)=\frac{1}{x}. $$

The function $g$ is convex on $D$, but the function

$$ H(x)=g(h(x))=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{x}-x^2} $$

is *concave* on $D$.

In general, the composition *is* d.c., under some mild assumptions. See Theorem H in [this paper](http://www.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/~rokyta/preprint/2007-pap/2007-242.pdf).

**Edit**

As Kavi Rama Murthy notes in the comments, to disprove that $H$ is not convex in general, you could take any two convex functions $h_1,h_2$ such that $h_1-h_2$ is not convex (*e.g.* $h(x)=0-x^2$) then compose with $g(x)=x$ (the identity). This is algebraically much simpler than my counterexample above.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: $g(x)=x$ is convex and $h_1-h_2$ need not be convex.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Even simpler.